# Hive timestamp import from netezza

Tags: hadoop, hive, etl, netezza

I an ETLing a Netezza DB into a Hive target DB but I keep getting issues when it concerns timestamps. The source DB for the ETL to Netezza is Oracle and the "dates" there are stored as varchar. When Etled to Netezza they undergo a transformation into the netezza format and are accepted correctly.

When extracting this data from Netezza into hive I get an exception from java.sql.Timestamp that the timestamp is not in the appropriate format.

Note: due to the nature and specificity of the error on this system I cannot show output or logs

Comment: In what format is it stored in Oracle db.

Comment: Stored as varchar2 in the format yyyymmdd

Comment: can you please check https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-Timestamps your variable is not a timestamp can you change the variable type to date or concat some dummy HH:MM:SS.fffffffff so that it becomes a timestamp